# xyplot bottom axis when last row has fewer panels than columns

Tags: r, plot, lattice

Consider a lattice `xyplot` that has `relation='fixed'`, `alternating=FALSE`, and `as.table=TRUE`.

If the last row of panels is incomplete (i.e. there are fewer panels than columns of the layout), the x-axis is not plotted. For example, panel 4 in the plot below does not have x-axis ticks/labels.

```
library(lattice)
d <- data.frame(x=runif(100), y=runif(100), grp=gl(5, 20))
xyplot(y~x|grp, d, as.table=TRUE, scales=list(alternating=FALSE, tck=c(1, 0)))
```

[image]

How can I add that axis?

Ideally I want axes only at bottom and left sides, and the incomplete row of panels at bottom (unlike when using `as.table=FALSE`, which plots the incomplete row at the top). For the example above, I'd like the axis plotted on the bottom border of panel 4, rather than in line with the x-axis of panel 5.

I know that this is easily solved with, e.g., a base graphics approach. I'm specifically interested in a lattice solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not a lattice expert, but I believe this might work. The idea was originally posted [here](http://thebiobucket.blogspot.de/2011/04/r-graphs-lattice-use-of-panel-functions.html). First I will regenerate the example:

```
library(lattice)
set.seed(1)
d <- data.frame(x=runif(100), y=runif(100), grp=gl(5, 20))
```

Next, lets define a function that will control the *panel* settings:

```
trellis.par.set(clip = list(panel = "off"))
myPan <- function(...){
    panel.xyplot(...)
    if(panel.number() == 4) {
        at = seq(0,1,by = 0.2)
        panel.axis("bottom", at = at, outside = T,
                    labels = T, half = F)
    }
    if(panel.number() == 5) {
        at = seq(0,1,by = 0.2)
        panel.axis("bottom",at = at, outside = T,
                   labels = T, half = F)
    }
}
```

Now to the plot:

```
xyplot(y~x|grp, d, as.table=TRUE, 
       scales = list(
           x = list(draw = F, relation="same"),
           y = list(tck=c(1,0), alternating=F)),
       layout = c(2,3),
       panel = myPan)
```

As can be seen, in the `xyplot` command we asked not to draw the x axis (`draw = F`) but later panel calls `myPan` function. There we specifically demand to draw x-axis for panels 4 and 5.

#### output

[image]

Hope it can give you some direction for improvements.

Comment: I am sorry, I left out this line from the answer `trellis.par.set(clip = list(panel = "off"))`. This should go before the xyplot command. I edited the answer to include it.

Comment: Nice. And you can add `trellis.par.set(clip = list(panel = "off"),layout.heights=list(axis.xlab.padding=3))` to avoid squishing the label "x" along the bottom.

Comment: Thanks for this. You actually don't need to suppress the axis in the `xyplot` call - you can simplify it to `xyplot(y~x|grp, d, as.table=TRUE, scales=list(tck=c(1,0), alternating=FALSE), panel=myPan)`. That sorts out the x-axis title too.

Comment: (And in that case, the `if(panel.number() == 5)` expression can be removed from the panel function.)

Comment: Right, because it will happen automatically. Smart, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another approach based on code provided in a (now deleted) answer by @user20650. It uses `grid` directly, focussing on panels of the active trellis plot that are missing axes (or at least *assumed* to be missing axes), and adding them. We also assume that the x-scale is fixed.

The function (which also exists as a gist [here](https://gist.github.com/johnbaums/e799ebd3f9468a05e359)):

```
add_axes <- function() {
  library(grid)
  library(lattice)
  l <- trellis.currentLayout()
  pan <- which(l[nrow(l), ]==0)
  if(length(pan) > 0) {
    g <- grid.ls(print=FALSE)
    # use an existing panel as a template for ticks 
    ticks <- grid.get(g$name[grep("ticks.bottom.panel", g$name)][[1]])
    # use an existing panel as a template for labels
    labels <- grid.get(g$name[grep("ticklabels.bottom.panel", g$name)][[1]])
    ax <- grobTree(ticks, labels)
    invisible(sapply(pan, function(x) {
      trellis.focus("panel", x, nrow(l)-1, clip.off=TRUE)
      grid.draw(ax)
      trellis.unfocus()  
    }))
  }
}
```

An example:

```
library(lattice)
d <- data.frame(x=runif(100), y=runif(100), grp=gl(5, 20))
xyplot(y~x|grp, d, as.table=TRUE, scales=list(tck=c(1,0), alternating=FALSE), 
       layout=c(4, 2), xlim=c(-0.1, 1.1))
```

[image]

```
add_axes()
```

[image]

Comment: @user20650 - it's been very handy... that issue has been bugging me for a couple of years but I never put the time into working it out. Thanks again.